# Отобразить по наведению по ссылке превью заголовок и картинку со страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Сабж. Я новичок в html, css и в js. Требуется отобразить при наведению на ссылку заголовок страницы Wikipedia и картинку с этой страницы. Каким способом это можно сделать? Предлагайте вообще любой способ, с помощью js, css, не важно, главное, чтобы работало.

Пробовал:

```css
.box {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}
a:hover + .box,
.box:hover {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
This live preview for <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/">Wikipedia</a>
<div class="box">
  <iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org/" width="500px" height="500px"></iframe>
</div>remains open on mouseover.
```

Но это показывает превью **всей** страницы

Нашел это. Можно ли использовать эту фичу на странице?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Tools/Navigation_popups

Comment: [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) не позволит сделать то, что вы задумали.

Comment: А что насчет каких-нибудь фреймворков для js, или вышеуказанного Wikipedia navigation popups?

Comment: Что нельзя сделать на чистом js, нельзя сделать на фреймворках. А Wikipedia navigation popups работают только на самой Wikipedia.

Comment: Т.е использовать код выше - единственный выход?

Comment: А что означает, *Требуется отобразить при наведению на ссылку заголовок страницы Wikipedia и картинку с этой страницы*? Картинок на странице может быть множество. И какой заголовок? То, что находится в теге **title**?

Comment: Картинку первую и title

Comment: А что мешает аяксом подтянуть html страницы и распарсить его?